# Is there a way to pass Runnable (or Callable) to IntentService?

Tags: android

Note: This is not asking about whether the data is to be marshalled into Intent and then derive a specific and concrete implementation of IntentService for those.

So my standard IntentService implementation is working fine and all but I'm interested if say I can pass a more generic type (e.g. network Runnables, I/O task Callables etc etc.) to an IntentService and let it runs its course.

While I know it is already achievable with Java concurrent package (especially ExecutorService), I'm liking the ease of IntentService and the associated framework around which is very ideal for a highly decoupled Android task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my standard IntentService implementation is working fine and all
>   but I'm interested if say I can pass a more generic type (e.g. network
>   Runnables, I/O task Callables etc etc.) to an IntentService and let it
>   runs its course.

You can't pass it. What you could is creating a `Factory`, which creates your subclass of Runnable/Callable, and depending on the action you provide in the `intent`, ask the `Factory` to build on of the concrete instances, and then call `instance.run()` or `instance.call()`. E.g.

```
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { 
    YourFactory.create(intent.getAction()).run();
}
```

Comment: Really gotta say this the most neatest implementation (plus being Android-like) that I even wonder how it wasn't far more obvious. Plus it is far more composable too. Thanks!

Comment: Nice idea, was looking for something to make universal foreground services